# How can I duplicate all the rows of a table into the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 20 fields and only 5 rows. None of the fields are unique, indexed or primary keys.

I want to simply duplicate all 5 rows in the table. Is there a single SQL statement to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query should fulfill your requirement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

If you want to copy all fields from another table then,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

If you want to copy only specific fields then,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(field1,field2) SELECT field1,field2 FROM TABLE2;
```

Please note that field count in `INSERT` and `SELECT`should be the same.